12 V light switch
I recently added solar to my shed powering a 12 V light in there. It currently has no on/off switch which I want to add. I also want to add another light which complicates things. Is there a simple diagram/explanation that a newby could follow to achieve this?
Thank you.

You need to tell us the power rating (watts) of the 12 V light and the second light and what switching arrangement you want. [Edit] all the information into your question - not in the comments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you sure you want to DIY this? The problem is also not what wire to connect and where, but also what wire to choose and how to fasten it, both electrically and mechanically. The problem is not safety as in deadly voltages, the problem is high short-circuit currents melting wires or causing them to glow red hot and starting fires.

The question mentions "added solar" which suggests a solar panel is involved. What is the maximum current the solar panel can produce, and is there also a battery involved which is charged during daylight hours to allow the 12 V light to be used at say night time?

So are you wondering what type of switch you need or how to connect it with something? Do you have enough power for 2 lights?

Buy a suitable switch (make sure it is rated for at least 12 volts DC, and at least as many amps as your lights use), cut one of the wires going to the lights, and connect the switch to the two cut ends. When the switch is turned on it joins the two cut ends, completing the circuit. When the switch is turned off it does not complete the circuit.
You can have more than one lighting circuit from the same power source by joining another the wires from the second light onto the wires you already have that go to the first light. You can join the wire with the switch on either the lighting side of the switch, or the power source side of the switch. If you make it so the power for both lights has to go through the switch, the switch will control both lights. If you make it so it doesn't, it won't. You can even have two switches, one for each light. If you make it so the power has to go through two switches, both of them have to be on to complete the circuit.
You should make sure the wires are thick enough for the amount of current (amps) that the lights will use. Since this is just a light for a shed I assume that not much is needed and any random wire from the hardware store is good enough, but it's good to check. Wire size is measured in AWG or in mm² and you can find some random chart on the internet as a guide.
"Justme" mentions the danger of short circuits, but if we were all so paranoid about safety, nobody would ever DIY anything. You've already wired up one light. It's a good idea to have a fuse in line with either wire, close to the power source, so if you do accidentally make a short circuit, you should only have to replace the fuse, and no wires will get melted. Strictly speaking, this is optional.
Note: This is an answer focused on the electrical aspects - I have no idea about the building code.
